# Make documents where the date printed on the document is automatically the date of creation of document

Tags: r, datetime, date, datetime2

Is there a way to create latex documents where the date printed on the documents is always by default the date of creation of the document?

I don't want to compile the same latex file 30 days later and have the date be changed to the most recent time it was compiled.

If not, is there a way to hard-code the date on the document in the American format, Month/Day/Year?

Using Day/Month/Year confuses me.

I'm using R's latex editor.

Comment: What do you mean by "the date of creation" if it's not "the most recent time it was compiled"?

Comment: The first time I created the latex file is the date of creation: The first time is the first compilation time. The most recent time is was compiled is not the first time it was compiled.

Comment: do you mean the internal creation date metadata in the PDF file or the date in a title, in the later case for most document classes just use `\date{whatever string you want here}`

Comment: do I use the datetime package?

Comment: @Numbers only if you want to use it (it is not very related to your question)

Comment: The datetime(2) package will transform a given date into a particular format.  To get that given date is a different question.  `\today` will give the date the document was last compiled, which you don't want.  The date the tex file was created (or last modified) are not normally known to TeX, so you'd need an outside program to do that (R might be able to help there).  But as David Carlisle mentioned, you can always do `\date{01/08/2020}` and manually set the date to be whatever you want.

Comment: Wild guesses here. Getting the time of first compilation (f.c.) on every future compilation might not be fully automatable. The date and time of f.c. are afaik only recorded in the metadata of the files created during f.c.. Of course, these files and their metadata are overwritten when compiling again. Storing this info involves some degree of manual work. Based on that, the easiest solution is to include the info in your document manually like described in the other comments.

Comment: I wrote a lab journal, where I included both the time of creation (explicitly also in the source code as yyyy-mm-dd) and the time of last compilation with `\today`.

Comment: Athough some filesystem as ext4 now can store the birdth date of a file, in most cases  this is not sored in any way, so you can reterive the date of the last modification or the last access, but not the creation date. Therefore,  the best solution is to declare it honestly iwith plain text.